# Query funciona no phpmyadmin, mas não no Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin

Galera,

O Laravel ajuda muito, mas quando ele quer complicar também, complica de verdade.
Eu fiz uma query e testei no phpmyadmin e funciona normalmente, mas insiro a query no meu projeto o Laravel dá erro. Já tentei com o Database usando DB::table, DB::select etc., já tentei com Eloquent. Todo resultado de query de qualquer jeito que eu faça, funciona no phpmyadmin, mas não funciona no Laravel.
Alguém me ajude, por favor.

O que eu preciso é o seguinte:

```
$sql = "select *, 
        (select order_date from orders where order_number = order_id) as order_date, 
        (select client_id from orders where order_number = order_id) as client_id, 
        (select name from clients where id = client_id) as client_name, 
        (select sum(quant)) as saldo 
        from order_products 
        inner join orders on order_number = order_id 
        where product_id = 5 and complete_order = 0 
        group by order_id 
        order by order_id asc";
```

Já fiz das seguintes maneiras:

```
$data = DB::select($sql);
```

e

```
$data = DB::table('order_products')
        ->select(['order_date' => Order::select('order_date')->whereColumn('order_number', 'order_id')])
        ->addSelect(['client_id' => Order::select('client_id')->whereColumn('order_number', 'order_id')])
        ->addSelect(['name' => Client::select('name')->whereColumn('id', 'client_id')])
        ->addSelect(DB::raw('sum(quant) as saldo'))
        ->where('product_id', $id)
        ->where('complete_order', 0)
        ->join('orders', 'order_number', 'order_id')
        ->groupBY('order_id')
        ->orderBy('order_id')
        ->paginate(20);
```

Entre muitas outras tentativas, inclusive com Eloquent.

Quando debugo o SQL resultado dessas tentativas, todas funcionam no phpmyadmin, mas sempre dá erro no Laravel. O último erro que está dando é o seguinte:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'aptcontrol.orders.client_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from (select (select `order_date` from `orders` where `order_number` = `order_id`) as `order_date`, (select `client_id` from `orders` where `order_number` = `order_id`) as `client_id`, (select `name` from `clients` where `id` = `client_id`) as `name`, sum(quant) as saldo from `order_products` inner join `orders` on `order_number` = `order_id` where `product_id` = 6 and `complete_order` = 0 group by `order_id`) as `aggregate_table`)
```

Desculpa se ficou grande a explicação, pois tentei fazer o mais detalhado possível.

Desde já agradeço a ajuda!

Comment: Essa SQL é bad SQL deveria repensar como escrever, e em relação ao Eloquent, não está sendo traduzido igual a sua SQL pura e por isso dos erros, não é problema no Eloquent é problema como foi feito.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica. Eu resolvi alterando em Config > Database > mysql > strict => true (mudei para true), resolveu mas você tem razão, tenho que melhorar essa query. Parou de dar erro e está funcionando, só não sei se isso é gambiarra. De qualquer forma, obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver galera, obrigado pelas dicas.

Este erro estava acontecendo por causa do GROUP BY, mas eu não me aprofundei, confesso.

Resolvi da seguinte forma:

Na pasta config > Database, no array do mysql, dentro de connections, tem um item chamado "strict". Ele está com o valor 'true' eu mudei para 'false'.
Só fazendo isso, não deu mais erro e o Laravel leu minha query e retornou o resultado.

Segundo este link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42104412/what-is-the-use-of-strict-in-laravel-config-database/42104555 , a desativação do strict, colocando como 'false', não torna sua aplicação menos segura, se você seguir as boas práticas que o Laravel recomenda.

Agradeço a todos!